# json_encode не ставит квадратную скобку

Tags: php, json, list, json-encode

```
$array = [
    '111' => '1111',
    '222' => [
        '333' => '3333',
        '444' => '444'
    ]
];
var_dump( json_encode( $array ) );
?>
```

Ожидаю получить

```
string(47) "{"111":"1111","222":[{"333":"3333","444":"444"}]}"
```

А получаю

```
string(47) "{"111":"1111","222":{"333":"3333","444":"444"}}"
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Всё верно. Скобки означают вложенный массив, которого у Вас нет

Answer (score 1):

Ожидаемая конструкция `[{"333":"3333","444":"444"}]` лишена смысла, потому что вы ожидаете массив с одним элементом в котором находится всё тот же объект с множеством элементов, вместо того, чтобы ожидать сразу этот объект

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы же даёте на вход ассоциативный массив с двумя элементами ключ-значение, вы его на выходе и получаете. Т.к. в JS ассоциативный массив - объект - результат закономерен.

Answer (score 0):

Понял. Нужно писать

```
$array = [
    '111' => '1111',
    '222' => [[
        '333' => '3333',
        '444' => '444'
    ]]
];
```